# Converting a basic Cocoa application to a document-based application

Tags: cocoa

My team and I have been working on an existing, non-document-based Cocoa application. This is our first Cocoa app, although we've done a number of iOS apps thus far.

The app really should be document-based, though, so I've begun trying to convert it. But things here & there don't seem to be working. For example, the File -> Open menu item is permanently disabled (although I finally got the File -> Save menu item to enabled; initially it wouldn't). In addition, I can click the red X to close a window, although the File -> Close menu item itself is disabled; however, when I close the window via the X button, the dealloc method in my NSDocument implementation (SPDocumentInfo) is not invoked. I created a sample, brand-new document-based app just for comparisons; when I close a window there, the SPDocument implementation's dealloc method is indeed invoked (as I'd expect.) So that concerns me.

I made a lot of changed to the project here and there; they include:

- Made SPDocumentInfo extend SPDocument like so in the .h file:

  ```
  @interface SPDocumentInfo : NSDocument <NSWindowDelegate>
  ```
- Implemented the following in SPDocumentInfo:

  ```
  - (NSString *)windowNibName {
      return @"SPDocument";
  }

  - (void)windowControllerDidLoadNib:(NSWindowController *) aController {
      [super windowControllerDidLoadNib:aController];
  }

  - (NSData *)dataOfType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
      NSString *xml = [self toXml];
      return [xml dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
  }

  - (BOOL)readFromData:(NSData *)data ofType:(NSString *)typeName error:(NSError **)outError {
      // will make this work later
      if ( outError != NULL ) {
          *outError = [NSError errorWithDomain:NSOSStatusErrorDomain code:unimpErr userInfo:NULL];
      }
      return YES;
  }
  ```
- Edited the .plist file to add "Document types". Among other things, defined "Cocoa NSDocument Class" = "SPDocumentInfo".
- Altered some connections in SPDocumentInfo to match the connections in the sample document-based app. For example, in SPDocument.nib, the File's Owner (which represents SPDocumentInfo) is the Window's delegate.

So, I'm wondering if there are other sorts of things I might be missing in converting to a doc-based app. Or, are there any guides on how to do this? (I've looked but couldn't find any). Or should I just start over with a new document-based app and try to retrofit all of our stuff into it? In general, does anyone have any experience with this?

Comment: Quick update, in case anyone is following. I realized that earlier, we'd mucked around a bit with connecting some menu items to specific outlets we'd created, rather than letting them remain pointed to their default First Responder outlets. Once I restored the default connections, the menu items became enabled.

As far as the dealloc method not being called as expected, I suspect that we have an issue of circular dependencies, where classes contains references to each other and therefore never get to a retain count of zero (which, I guess, is a whole other topic). So we might be able to solv

Comment: Another update: I don't think the issue is one of circular dependencies. I overrode the release methods in both my SPDocumentInfo class, and the MyDocument class in the sample app. When I close a window in the sample app, release is called by [NSDocumentController removeObject] and [NSWindowController _windowDidClose] (as well as a few autorelease pool pops). But *none* of that happens to SPDocumentInfo when I close the window in my app. So somehow, the document controller and/or window controller is not behaving as expected in my app.

Answer (score 5):

An often found suggestion is to create a new document based application and move all you existing code in there. This can be cumbersome for a large workspace with all kinds of stuff nicely configured. Let alone breaking version control.

I took the following simple steps and it worked:

- Generate a document based application
- from this this generated project, copy the following section from the Info.plist (open the file with a normal text-editor):

  ```
  <key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
  <array>
      <dict>
          <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
          <array>
              <string>mydoc</string>
          </array>
          <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
          <string></string>
          <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
          <string>DocumentType</string>
          <key>CFBundleTypeOSTypes</key>
          <array>
              <string>????</string>
          </array>
          <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
          <string>Editor</string>
          <key>NSDocumentClass</key>
          <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).Document</string>
      </dict>
  </array>
  ```

  and paste it in the Info.plist file in your own project.
- Copy Document.swift from the generated document-based project into your own project.
- it contains a method:

  ```
  override func makeWindowControllers() {
      // Returns the Storyboard that contains your Document window.
      let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
      let windowController = storyboard.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "Document Window Controller") as! NSWindowController
      self.addWindowController(windowController)
  }
  ```

  It creates a new window just the way you application normally would. If you storyboard has only one windowcontroller the 'withIDentifier'-field can contain something arbitrary. If you have more window controllers in your storyboard, the identifier needs to correspond to the right windowcontroller for new documents.

Answer (score 5):

Everything @Hans' answer provides is correct, but the final change that is needed is totally, stupidly trivial, but adds a nontrivial amount of functionality that comes with document-based apps:

**In the `Main.storyboard` file, the `document` element has an extra property that needs to be deleted: `initialViewController="XXX-XX-XXX"`.**

It is probably the last thing on second line. Remove this, and the `Save…` menu option, along with a few other menu options, will properly be enabled by default, and the app will properly recognize the document object upon launch.

Comment: This did it for me. Initially, I removed the "initial controller" from the storyboard view, which also removed it from the source view of the storyboard. It wasn't until I added it back in storyboard view and removed it from source view that it worked.

Comment: This worked for me too. I did it in interface builder by clicking on the arrow pointing to the window (called "Storyboard Entry Point" in the object list) and deleting it. After that, the app now calls my Document class on startup.

Comment: Try to clean the build folder by pressing CMD+k if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, this time I legitmately **do** have a solution to present.

It turns out I had a "window" instance variable in SPDocumentInfo (which as you'd guess pointed to the NSWindow associated with the document). That appeared to caused a chain of events (or more likely, prevented a chain of events) which led to SPDocumentInfo's dealloc not being called when it should have. I didn't catch that when I was comparing my project to the sample doc-based project, because apparently SPDocument **also** has a member variable called "window" which is **also** connected to the relevant NSWindow. I saw that connection in the sample project, and it looked identical to my project's connection, so I didn't think twice about it.

In other words, part of my problem was that I just coincidentally decided to connect up a "window" outlet NSDocument implementation, and didn't realize that I was actually shadowing a superclass variable (which I'm guessing is, unlike mine, configured as "assign" and not "retain").

So, things seem okay at this point, and I think I can declare that it is indeed possible (and my nagging issue notwithstanding, generally painless) to convert from a non-doc-based app to a doc-based one.

Answer (score 3):

This is more of an opinion than a direct answer, but if you're new to the Mac side and to document-based applications, your path of least resistance would definitely be to create a new doc-based Xcode project from the template and move your relevant code over, plugging it into the template places where needed.

Comment: Joshua,

Thanks for the response. And yeah, you might be right. I'll probably start a separate doc-based project and see how easy it is port stuff over (the code, I'm not so concerned with. It's really all of the stuff we'd done in the NIB file, including all of the complex wirings, that I'm concerned about).

Partly, I feel like I'm *almost* there, and maybe there's just one thing missing. And partly, this seems like a good exercise in understanding exactly what goes on "under the covers" in a doc-based app.