# Core Data non-document to document-based application?

Tags: core-data

Is there a way to transform a Core Data non-document application to a document-based application?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, probably there are several ways.

Comment: I would be glad to find some discussion about this, but I didn't  find anything. I would like to avoid dealing with the data file. As I understand, the NSPersistentDocument will provide all that file management.

Comment: It is the same as transforming a Cocoa non-document application to a document-based application without Core Data. [converting app to a document based app](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev%40lists.apple.com/msg67162.html), [Converting to NSPersistentDocument](http://www.mail-archive.com/cocoa-dev%40lists.apple.com/msg10105.html) and [Converting a basic Cocoa application to a document-based application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097758/converting-a-basic-cocoa-application-to-a-document-based-application)

Comment: Great! I will read the links you sent me. Thank you!